# MAC filtering using iptables/ebtables

Tags: iptables, ebtables

I'm trying to drop a MAC address on a node in my network. Now, I tried two tools iptables and ebtables, but both attempts failed:

- `iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:0F:EA:91:04:08 -j DROP` resulting in "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name."
- `ebtables -A INPUT -s 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j DROP` resulting in "FATAL: Module ebtables not found. The kernel doesn't support the ebtables 'filter' table."

I'm working with Kernel version 2.6.32: `uname -r` results in "2.6.32-042stab049.6.emulab.1"

How can I make (at least one) it work? I've searched about this failures, but not much information is to be found. How do I make the kernel support the ebtables 'filter' table? How come there is "no chain/target/match by that name"?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you can actually list an INPUT chain:

```
# iptables -L
```

Hopefully that should something akin to:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

As for ebtables, it apparently isn't actually part of your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the ebtables options in your Kernel configuration

```
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_BROUTE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_NAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_802_3=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_AMONG=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP6=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_STP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_VLAN=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARPREPLY=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_DNAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK_T=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_SNAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_LOG=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ULOG=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_NFLOG=y
```

then build the kernel and retry. Its also possible that something iptables relates is missing also.